# head tags doesn't change in dynamic page with next/head

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm building a Ecommerce site and i'm making the product detail page. I need to change the meta tags of the page according to the product attributes. I'm using the head component from next/head. The problem is that it seems than the metas change only when I inspect the page with chrome dev tools, but when I choose see the source page they don't appear.
It's important to me that the metas change from server beacuse I need use og metas for facebook sharing.
I'm using next v9, and i'm using a custom server, also I use _document and _app prebuild pages.

this is my _document page

[image]

And this is my product detail page

[image]

and in the chrome view page source option I only see the document head metas but not the product detail page ones.

[image]

Can anyone help me to unsderstand how I shloud use head? I have tried several examples with no success.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?? I am also facing an issue like this here https://stackoverflow.com/q/61073587/12856847 but couldn't get right solution..

Answer (score 1):

Add the `key` parameter to your `_document.js` meta tags as well. Those will be loaded first, but then overwritten (server side) if you have a `meta` with a matching key in your `pages` file.

Also note - I don't think the colon works in the `key` parameter like you have in the product detail page, nor does `property` exist on a meta tag.

So if you have something like this:

```js
// _document.js
<meta key="ogType" name="og:type" content="website" />
```

...this will be the default meta tag on your pages. But then if you have:

```js
// pages/blog.js
<meta key="ogType" name="og:type" content="article" />
```

...on the blog page, the `og:type` meta tag will be the one used.